# Can't access domain class methods in loaded template

Tags: grails, gsp

I'm using Grails 1.3.8 (old but gold). In my view I render a template with the same variables as of the containing view via:

```
<g:render template="areaInfoTemplate" model="${pageScope.variables}"/>
```

This works unless I try to access methods on domain classes **inside the template**:

```
<g:if test="${currentState == State.findByName('foobar')}">...</g:if>
```

Leads to:

```
Exception Message: Cannot invoke method findByName() on null object
```

If I access `State` in the main view gsp everything is ok.

My domain class is:

```
class State {
    String name
    String value

    static constraints = {
        name(nullable:false,blank:false,size:0..255)
        value(nullable:false,blank:false,size:0..255)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Grails isn't PHP - please don't make database calls from the view layer (unless you like to fight artificial, self-inflicted scalability issues). Just make the calls in a controller or service and pass the data to the view to be rendered. GSPs should only be responsible for rendering output, not higher-level concerns like database access.

Comment: You are right. Will be fixed... But for what usecase is that import statement then?

Comment: Never say never :)  Sometimes it's more pragmatic to do the work in a GSP, and when you want to do some logic in a template that's used by different controllers (or all of them) it can be difficult to move the logic to the controller tier and stay DRY. But in most cases a taglib is a great option - you're still doing view-only work in the views, and offloading business logic and database access to taglib classes and their helpers, usually dependency-injected services.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add an import statement at the beginning of the file:

```
<%@ page import="my.wonderful.package.State"%>
```

Comment: This may work for you but it is not a solution. listen to @burt